# Powers of 13 expressable as sums of squares

Tags: number-theory

Show that
$$13^k=a^2+b^2,k\in \mathbb{N}$$
has only one solution $(a,b)$
where $a,b\in \mathbb{N^{+}}，gcd(a,b)=1$.

For example, $$13=2^2+3^2$$
$$13^2=169=5^2+12^2$$

I  think this is very interesting problem. Thank you everyone.

Comment: But there is always more than one integer solution...$13 = 2^2 + 3^2 = (-2)^2 + 3^2 = 2^2 + (-3)^2 = (-2)^2 + (-3)^2$.

Comment: The statement is false, e.g. $$13^3 = 26^2 + 39^2 = 9^2 + 46^2$$

Comment: What is true is that it has only one solution with $0\lt a\lt b$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: The solutions can be obtained from looking at the real and imaginary part of $(2+3i)^k$.

Comment: Also, for even $k$, Hagen's solution is different from $13^k=\left(13^{\frac{k}{2}}\right)^2+0^2$, which gives an infinite number of counterexamples.

Comment: This interpretation using complex numbers is great. Thanks Hagen.

Answer (score 4):

The number of solutions of $13^{k} = a^{2} + b^{2}$ is given by "number of divisors of $13^{k}$ of the form $4n + 1$" minus "number of divisors of $13^{k}$ of the form $4n + 3$" and then multiply by $4$. Clearly $13^{k}$ has only $k + 1$ divisors of the form $4n + 1$ and no divisors of the form $4n + 3$, it follows that there are $4(k + 1)$ solutions of the equation $13^{k} = a^{2} + b^{2}$. Ignoring signs this becomes $k + 1$. Note that we are ignoring signs but counting $(a, b)$ and $(b, a)$ as two solutions, so that commutation is not ignored. So for the given question, unique solution is not guaranteed, but at least one solution is.

Comment: Proof for number of solutions formula can be found at http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-fourier-series.html

Comment: It is not the fact, that $13^k$ is of the form $4n+1$, that guarantes a solution, but rather that $13$ is of the form $4n+1$. Note, that $21$ is of that form, but not sum of two squares, because $3,7$ are not of that form.

Comment: Tomas you are correct. But as I explain the formula for number of solutions, if we try the number 21, we see that it has two divisors of the form $4n + 1$ (namely 1, 21) and two divisors of the form $4n + 3$ (3, 7) so that total number of solutions is zero. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing out the silly mistake.

Comment: Indeed! This is a very nice observation, I haven't seen it before (+1)

Comment: You might add, that "Number of $\equiv 1$-divisors minus number of $\equiv 3$-divisors" yields the number of solutions ignoring signs, but _not_ ignoring commutation.

Comment: Tomas, I have put your remark in the answer so as to remove some ambiguity about what is included in counting the solutions and what is not.

Comment: Paramanand: Nice! One last remark: In the $k$ odd case, this gives $\frac{k+1}{2}$ actual solutions. In the $k$ even case, dividing by four was wrong, because there are solutions where one square is $0^2$, thus not double counted. $\frac{k}{2}+1$ seem correct in this case.

Comment: sorry,I have edit, Thank you @ParamanandSingh,your link I can't open

Comment: Strange math110, this link to my blog is public and anybody can use it. However it uses mathjax (like math.stackexchange.com) and hence you need to wait for math symbols to load.

Answer (score 3):

Known facts:

1. $13$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$.
2. For every prime $p$ of the from $4k+1$, there are integers $1 \le x < y < p$ such that
   $p = x^2 + y^2$. In particular, $13 = 2^2 + 3^2 = (2+3i)(2-3i)$.
3. $\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{\;x + i y : x, y \in \mathbb{Z}\;\}$, the set of [Guassian integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) is a [unique factorization domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain) with
   units $\pm 1, \pm i$ and three type of primes:

   1. $1+i\quad$ ( $1-i$ is equivalent to $1+i$ through a unit ).
   2. $x+iy, x-iy\quad$ where $x^2 + y^2 = p$ is a prime of the form $4k+1$.
      The $x \pm iy$ are inequivalent over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
   3. $p$ a prime of the form $4k+3$.

Since $13 = (2+3i)(2-3i)$, in any representation of $13^k$ as a sum of squares:

$$13^k = a^2 + b^2 = (a+bi)(a-bi)\tag{*1}$$
the unique factorization property of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ forces $a + ib$ to have the form:

$$a + bi = i^e (2 + 3i)^f (2-3i)^{k-f}\tag{*2}$$

where $0 \le e < 4$ and $0 \le f \le k$.

If $0 < f < k$, then the R.H.S of $(*2)$ contains a factor $(2+3i)(2-3i) = 13$. This will make $\gcd(a,b) > 1$ (or one of $a,b$ vanish). This means if one want a solution of $(*1)$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, $f$ can only be $0$ or $k$.

Notice the $f = 0$ case can be obtained from a $f = k$ case by taking complex conjugation. 
Furthermore, multiplication of $i^e$ either changes the signs of $a,b$ or exchange among them.

As a result, up to flipping the signs and/or exchaning $a$ with $b$, the unique solution of $(*1)$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ is given by (as pointed by other poster):

$$a + i b = (2+3i)^k$$